# How to determine what the branches are that are listed in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a java project whose coverage results are being pushed to SonarQube but I'm having a problem with a line in one of my classes. It says that only 1/6 branches are covered for the below line, however for the life of me I can't figure out what the 6 branches are, or why only one is being tested.

I have a test where datacenters is a list, and where datacenters is a string, so surely that would be there are at least 2 branches covered. I can't figure out what the other branches might be besides it being an instance of neither, or why it says only 1 branch is being covered.

If anyone has a suggestion as to what the other branches might be, or if this might just be a bug, please let me know.

```
assert (datacenters instanceof List || datacenters instanceof String);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/87) regarding this. sonarqube uses jacoco code coverage. It shows the number of branches covered or missed  but it doesn't show which one. I think you have a similar situation

Comment: Do you have a suggestion as to what 6 branches are at that line?